# Answer is completely made of copied content

Tags: discussion

This answer: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26102/3796 is made of 100% copied content from one or more sites.  Wouldn't that be against the spirit of this site?

The profile of these users have very similar questions/answers:

https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/3731/ice-girl
https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/7989/golnaz

Answer (score 4):

If you see answers that are plagiarized, flag them. Plagiarism is not okay. The answer you mention was edited to include links to the sources, so it is no longer plagiarism. However, we *do* very much prefer answers that explain things in your own words, rather than simply copy-pasting from other sources. What's the use of this site if that's all we do? But since that particular answer had a lot of useful information, a score of +10 and an accept, we edited in the source rather than deleting it.

So, just flag these and a mod will take the appropriate action (if you can provide a link to where the content was copied from, that *really* helps us).